# Remove those rows from a pyspark dataframe whose entries from a column are not present in a dictionary's list of keys

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark. I have a pyspark dataframe as follows:

```
+-----------+
|C1| C2 | c3| 
+-----------+
|A |0  | 1  |
|C |0  | 1  |
|A |1  | 0  |
|B |0  | 0  |
+-----------+
```

I also have another python dictionary as follows:

```
my_dict = {"A" : "5", "B" : "10"} # Not there is no entry with key 'C' here
```

What I would like to ensure is that my dataframe keeps only those rows whose **C1** column's values are present **as keys** inside the dictionary my_dict. The output should be somewhat like this:

```
+-----------+
|C1| C2 | c3| 
+-----------+
|A |0  | 1  |
|A |1  | 0  |
|B |0  | 0  |
+-----------+
```

*Edit* : The C1 column entries are a little more complicated than depicted above. Although it is a string, it has quite a few special characters. Something like this:

```
A : www.A.com || u-a : Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12H321 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBAV/163.0.0.54.96;FBBV/96876057;FBDV/iPhone7,1;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iPhone OS;FBSV/8.4.1;FBSS/3;FBCR/MEO;FBID/phone;FBLC/pt_PT;FBOP/5;FBRV/98697066] || C : none || accept-encoding : gzip, deflate, br || accept-language : en-US,en;q=0.9=223
```

The string above is used as a key in the dictionary as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using below syntax

```
input_data=[['A',0,1],['C',0,1],['A',1,0],['B',0,0]]
my_dict = {"A" : "5", "B" : "10"}
data = spark.createDataFrame(input_data)
input_key_list=[key for key in my_dict.keys()]

from pyspark.sql.functions import col
data.where(col("_1").isin(input_key_list)).show()
```

another approach could be -

```
input_data=[['A',0,1],['C',0,1],['A',1,0],['B',0,0]]
input_data_columns = ["c1","c2","c3"]
my_dict = {"A" : "5", "B" : "10"}
input_key_list=[key for key in my_dict.keys()]

from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType,StringType
keys_data=spark.createDataFrame(input_key_list, StringType())
data = spark.createDataFrame(input_data,schema=input_data_columns)
keys_data.join(data,data.c1 ==  keys_data.value,"inner").select("c1","c2","c3").show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am facing an issue with this piece of code. My "key" isn't as simple as let's say "A" [It has special characters in it although it is a string]. I have added how the key looks like in the description above. I get the following error while running your code: **py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.HashMap**. Can you please help here?

Comment: input_key_list is made out of keys only

Comment: Yes understood. May I know how efficient this is [if you are aware of it]? Can this be considered as an efficient way to solve the problem?

Comment: if the keys list is getting huge then another way could be to create dataframe out of keys list and the using join to filter out the records would be best way.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Are you referring to an inner join between dataframes here? If so could you please share an example or point me to an already existing one? As I am new to pyspark, I need a bit of handholding here.

Comment: i have added alternative approach in the ans